# copy content from one div to another

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

There are two divs, one with class="article_magazine_title" and 
the other with class="article_magazine_content"

How could I copy the first string till the " @ " starts from the class="article_magazine_content" div,
(in my example "RSS Circus") and 
paste/inject it in the class="article_magazine_title" div?

```
<div class="article_magazine_title" dir="ltr">
<a class="article_magazine_title_link" href="https://twitter.com/RSSCircus/status/943033603855998978" onmouseup="return toggle_articleview('14130930314',false,event,{dont_scroll:true})" id="at_14130930314">It’s a sad day, but Minimal Reader has officially shut down</a>
</div>

<div id="article_magazine_content_14130930314" class="article_magazine_content" dir="ltr">RSS Circus@RSSCircus It’s a sad day, but Minimal Reader has officially shut down </div>
```

this condition should apply only if the anchor contained in the div contains href="https://twitter.com/*" (greasemonkey)

Comment: You tried anything yet or just assigned a task for Stackoverflow community?

Comment: I didn't try ...

Comment: @patrickdrd [**How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users before posting a Question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/448144) - You are asking multiple questions, extracting part of a string and copying DOM content. Search for that, have a go and if you have issues post your code in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for use to help you with.

Answer (score -2):

Try following code:

```
$('.article_magazine_title a[href^="https://twitter.com/"]').text($('.article_magazine_content').text().split('@')[0]);
```

Comment: You are assuming OP uses jQuery and you are not explaining that this is a JQuery solution. You should at least explain that this is what you are using and what it is you are doing exactly. The way it is written now it is easily confusing to anyone that doesn't use jQuery or has no idea about string functions like split.

Comment: it didn't work 

    window.addEventListener('click', event => {
  $('.article_magazine_title a[href^="https://twitter.com/"]').text($('.article_magazine_content').text().split('@')[0]);
}

Comment: @fran: correct,
how should I use jquery in greasemonkey?

Comment: ok, I added 
    // @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

but still doesn't work

Comment: @patrickdrd to work my script you should confirm that your DOM is loaded or try with document.ready: $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.article_magazine_title a[href^="https://twitter.com/"]').text($('.article_magazine_content').text().split('@')[0]);
})

Comment: @patrickdrd You don't need jQuery for it, it does make things contextually easier but unless you are planning to use jQuery throughout your project it's sill to add it for a single function.

Comment: all I know is 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.article_magazine_title a[href^="https://twitter.com/"]').text($('.article_magazine_content').text().split('@')[0]);
}
didn't work